# Defining regions for `Exclusions`

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have the following function I want to plot in 3D (For simplicities sake we can say $a=5,b=-1,c=3$.)

```
f[x_, y_, a_, b_,c_] := ((E^(b x) - E^(b y)) x)/((c E^(a b) + E^(b x)) (x - y))
```

However, when I plot it I get error messages for Intermediate values. To try to solve this I used `Exclusions`, but despite this I still get the same error messages.

```
Plot3D[{f[x, y,5,-1,3]}, {x, 9, 10}, {y, 9, 10}, Exclusions -> {x - y == 0}]
```

I thought I should maybe exclude the values `-0.1<=x-y<=0.1`, but I don't really know how to do it or if it works. Another thought I had was maybe use the conditions that result from using reduce. However, I'm not sure how to use the results to exclude intermediate values.

```
Reduce[f[x, y,5,-1,3] == 0, x]
```

Any suggestions on other ways to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you mind error messages ? Try e.g. `Plot3D[{f[x, y, 5, -1, 3]}, {x, 9, 10}, {y, 9, 10}] // Quiet` or if you need to exclude a region e.g. : `Plot3D[{f[x, y, 5, -1, 3]}, {x, 9, 10}, {y, 9, 10},RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[x - y] > 0.1]] // Quiet`

Comment: A simpler example: `Plot3D[1/(x - y), {x, 9, 10}, {y, 9, 10}, Exclusions -> {x == y}]`. Note that the message `Power::infy` only comes up once...

Comment: @Artes "Error message" might even be a misnomer, here. Maybe just a "warning" that something *might* be wrong, not necessarily that something *is* wrong.

Comment: @Artes it's not that I don't mind the error messages, it's just that I'm using it in a presentation and don't want the graph to produce messages.

Comment: @E.O. `Quit` just serves that purpose.

Comment: @Artes: yes, you won't get error messages after closing the kernel... ;)

Comment: @Artes I mean a slideshow made in mathematica with interactive content ;)

Comment: @J.M. Accidentally I wrote `Quit` instead of `Quiet`. But seriously, I belive `Quit` is a really good approach as well. E.g. the pioneers of computer science like `Leibniz` or `von Neumann` made their main discoveries without computers, even though they were interested in the related topics

Comment: @Artes, I was joking, of course. :) We've once discussed how easy it was to write one when the other was meant in chat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Quiet` to suppress the message, or re-define the function to exclude the problem points in the function definition:

```
 f1[x_, y_, a_, b_, c_] := ((E^(b x) - E^(b y)) x)/((c E^(a b) + E^(b x)) (x - y)) /;
   x != y;
 f2[x_, y_, a_, b_, c_] := Switch[x == y, True,   Indeterminate, 
   _, ((E^(b x) - E^(b y)) x)/((c E^(a b) +  E^(b x)) (x - y))];



Row[{Plot3D[Quiet@f[x, y, 5, -1, 3], {x, 9, 10}, {y, 9, 10},
      BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 250], 
    Plot3D[f1[x, y, 5, -1, 3], {x, 9, 10}, {y, 9, 10}, 
     BoxRatios -> 1,  ImageSize -> 250], 
    Plot3D[f2[x, y, 5, -1, 3], {x, 9, 10}, {y, 9, 10}, 
     BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 250]}]
```

[image]